# Locating a value in a csv from a list of lists

Tags: python

I have two lists that are grouped inside of a list. I’m trying to get an item out the list and check to see if it’s located in an csv column, if it is I want to retrieve a particular row. My attempt at it is below:

csv:

```
Name  Age
Susan 40 
Paul  45
Matt  22
Mary  28
Ben   25
Tom   32
```

code:

```
group = [['Paul', 'Matt'], ['Ben', 'Tom']]
ages = []

with open('People.csv') as fh:
spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')

for row in spreadsheet:
    for list in group:
        for person in list:
            if row['Name'] == str(person):
                ages.append(row['Age'])
print(ages)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't get your question properly. If you want to add the age of Paul, Matt, Ben, Tom to the age list from the People.csv. Your code looks fine except you need to add "import csv" at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flattening the list would simplify working with it:

```
import itertools

group = [['Paul', 'Matt'], ['Ben', 'Tom']]
flat_group = list(itertools.chain(*group))

with open('People.csv') as fh:
    spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')

ages = [row['Age'] for row in spreadsheet if row['Name'] in flag_group]
```